# How google crawler find each and every page over the internet

Tags: google-crawlers

Today i have one question that how google crawler find each and every page over the internet during crawling please share me the answers if you have.

Review the below link if you need any more on this.

[HOW SEARCH WORKS](https://www.google.co.in/insidesearch/howsearchworks/thestory/)

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Let me get this straight: You've read _all_ the information in that link you shared, and watched all the videos it provides, and you still don't understand how it works?  I don't think we can help you.  Also, this question does not appear to be about programming at all, or is too broad.

Comment: Yes but there is no specification about if you start from zero how you done the crawling on trillions of document over the internet and yes this question is not about programming so i do not assign programming language tags in this post...thanks...

Comment: Second paragraph of the _"Finding information by crawling"_ section of the [Crawling & Indexing](https://www.google.co.in/insidesearch/howsearchworks/crawling-indexing.html) page: _The crawl process begins with a list of web addresses from past crawls *and [sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en) provided by website owners*. As our crawlers visit these websites, they look for links for other pages to visit..._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that crawling is process of storing cached data, in cached data, the search engine looks for hyperlinks, may it be textual or image hyperlinks. Then after it has found one, it opens that page to cache and starts finding for links in it. The process goes on until there are no more links to be found.

So, in the this long chain of hyperlinks, it is almost certain that most of the internet is included. But, that doesn't mean that it has crawled everything. 
Many new websites are left out in this, because of lack of links to it.
and also some websites are not crawled because they are not intended to be discovered.

Comment: Thanks @Shashikant_ so is this process start with one specific page and it crawled most of the internet pages??

Comment: Yes. But, there are also systems to request crawls manually or priority wise, and if you have a new website, you are requested to submit the page manually to speed up the crawling process, or it might take days sometimes months for search engines to reach your website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy that means crawling database size is increase with time and we get better result after getting better crawling...